# Nginx: hide port for different domains on single server

Tags: nginx, dns, url-rewriting

I have 4 domains and 1 server. I install nginx and put 4 landing pages.

Example for one of them:

```
server {
   listen 2000;
   root /path/to;
   index index.html;
   server_name 1.1.1.1;
   location / {
       allow all;
   }
}
```

How I can redirect my domains for one of this landing pages? for example, when I open page http://mydomain.com i get landing page from address `1.1.1.1:2000`

Comment: Do you mean host multiple websites in one server? If so, simply have it listen to 1 port, and set the server_name and root path.

Comment: Yes, I use 1 server for 4 sites. Every of this sites have 1 unique page. For every of this pages I make there own ports. For one of them I make port `2000` for other `3000` and so on. Can you give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will listen on different ports. So you have to access it via `example1000.com:1000`. Or you could change all listen to 80, and access it via `example1000.com`, `example2000.com`, etc,.

```
server {  
  listen 1000;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name example1000.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /sites/example1000.com/public;

  # Index
  index index.html
}

server {  
  listen 2000;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name example2000.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /sites/example2000.com/public;

  # Index
  index index.html
}
```